# Uploading Django Development to Dreamhost/Passenger first time "Could no import"

Tags: python, django, installation, dreamhost

I've been developing on my laptop.

Now, I've uploaded my development project from Django 1.2/Python 2.7 up to Dreamhost created using the Passenger setup.  I am using South for migration.

I modified settings.py to access MySQL.  Got Admin working.

Questions:

1) Where is the std out shown when you hit the site? (all my print statements)

2) I had to add

```
from decimal import Decimal
```

to get the settings.py to run.

Now, hitting the server gives me a 500.  When I go to the commandline and try any manage.py command I'm getting:

Error: Could not import settings 'pholdershare.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): No module named settings

I modified the permissions for my folder to 755 but that didn't change anything.

3) Regarding development to testing to live, I'm totally unclear on how to do this.  I want to have a nice solid system for development where I can do releases but I've never done that.  I have been using GIT locally.  Can anybody point me to the tutorial on setting up the release system?

Suggestions?

Thanks much!

Comment: For that First question, you should avoid the use of print statements, and instead put up a decent logging solution. Read the docs about logging and django. And then have a look at django-sentry

Comment: Thanks.  Will look into django-sentry.

Comment: django-sentry may be cool, but if you're still trying to get up and running, start by: import logging at the top of your file and then replace all your print statements with logging.debug(blah)

Answer (score 0):

"Could not import settings 'pholdershare.settings'"
...usually means either settings.py has an import error or syntax error, or pholdershare has not been added to sys.path in your wsgi.py

Comment: does this help? http://www.soasi.com/2008/09/django-10-on-dreamhost-with-passenger-mod_rails/